# passing list to &rest args

Tags: emacs, elisp

How can I pass a list of parameters to `start-process`'s 4th argument `(PROGRAMS-ARGS)`:

```lisp
(start-process NAME BUFFER PROGRAM &rest PROGRAM-ARGS)
```

for example:

```lisp
(start-process "program-name" nil "program-name" "-p1" "-p2" "-p3" "program-name")
```

I want to do the same thing by collecting parameters in a list and passing the list variable to functions argument, but it doesn't work:

```lisp
(setq program-args (list "-p1" "-p2" "-p3"))

(start-process "program-name" nil "program-name" program-args "program-name")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [`apply`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Calling-Functions.html) in this case:

> apply calls function with arguments, just like funcall but with one
>   difference: the last of arguments is a list of objects, which are
>   passed to function as separate arguments, rather than a single list.

I.e., in your case the correct code is:

```
(apply 'start-process
  (append (list "program-name" nil "program-name")
          program-args
          (list "program-name")))
```